# Objective C CFSwapInt32

Tags: objective-c

I want to create a siple app which swaps the bytes of 2 and 4 byte hex codes.

So it should do: from 1234 to 3421 swap. I google and found out that I have to use byteorder and CFSwapInt32 and CFSwapInt16.

Here is what I already got:

```
NSString *byteOrder = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",CFSwapInt32(12345678)];
    NSLog(byteOrder);
```

But instead of the correct swapped bytes I get: 1315027968 as the number of the NSLog.

Can someone help me or tell me what I did wrong? :) I just want to swap bytes so they are in reversed order

```
1234 -->3412
12 34 -->34 12

12345678 -->78563412
12 34 56 78 --> 78 56 34 12
```

Thank you

Comment: `12345678` is in decimal. The bytes constituting it do not correspond to the digits. ;)

Comment: Also, you shouldn't use `CFSwapInt32()` directly. Prefer the variants that indicate the source order and desired order (e.g. `CFSwapInt32HostToBig()`). Not all systems store their bytes in the same order, and `CFSwapInt32()` will give different results depending on the system in use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
NSString *byteOrder = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%x",CFSwapInt32(0x12345678)];
```

`%x` will output a value as hexadecimal.

Starting a number with `0x` will interpret it as a hexadecimal value.

Answer (score 0):

Your original number is 12345678 which, in hex, is 0x00BC614E

The output you get in the log is 1315027968 which, in hex, is 0x4E61BC00

So everything is working correctly.

You can try doing the same in hex if you prefer:

```
NSString *byteOrder = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%x",CFSwapInt32(0x00BC614E)];
NSLog(byteOrder);
```

should log 0x4E61BC00 while

```
NSString *byteOrder = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%x",CFSwapInt32(0x12345678)];
NSLog(byteOrder);
```

should log 0x78563412

Comment: works thank you too. Unfortunately under 15 rep I cant vote you up